# Azure IoT hub and receiving anything

Tags: azure, iot

I'm trying to use Azure Iot hub for publishing and subscribing messages. At the moment I'm trying to publish some simple message with following command:

```
mosquitto_pub \
-h xxxdev.azure-devices.net \
-u "xxxdev.azure-devices.net/xxxdev/?api-version=2018-06-30" \
-P "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxx.azure- 
devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fxxxdev&sig=YYYYY&se=1570866689&skn=ZZZZZZZ" \
-t "devices/ublox1/messages/events/" \
--cafile ca.pem \
-p 8883 \
-i xxxdev \
-V mqttv311 \
-d \
-m 'message'
```

and subscribe with this one:

```
mosquitto_sub \
-h xxxdev.azure-devices.net \
-u "xxxdev.azure-devices.net/ublox1" \
-P "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxdev.azure- 
devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fublox1&sig=YYYYY&se=1607025033"
-t "devices/ublox1/messages/events/" \
-i xxxdev \
-V mqttv311 \
-p 8883 \
--cafile ca.pem  \
-v -d
```

but I cannot receive any of published messages. 
Here is what the output of the subscribe side:

```
Client xxxdev sending CONNECT
Client xxxdev received CONNACK (0)
Client xxxdev sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: topic/, QoS: 0, Options: 0x00)
Client xxxdev received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
```

and that is all. No PUBLISH messages I am able to receive on subscribe side.

My question is: what can be the reason that I cannot receive anything on subscriber side?

For testing purpose I run Visual Studio Code and run "Monitoring built-in event endpoint" - and it correctly shows my published messages - so what is going on? Why Visual Studio Code is able to shows my messages but mosquitto cannot?

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Hub is not a full-blown MQTT server/broker. In order to subscribe to telemetry messages coming from the devices, you need to use the [built-in event grid endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid). You can however use MQTT to subscribe to "cloud-to-device" messages, calls to direct methods, or device twin updates.